# How can I download a file directly to a web server?

Tags: download

I'd like to download files directly to a hosted server, whether it's one I set up myself or a hosted service like Dropbox.

For example, when I download a podcast, instead of downloading it to my computer then uploading it to the server, how can I have it download directly to the cloud.  My interest here is reducing the traffic I'm using over a metered data plan on my laptop, so I don't want my computer acting as a physical intermediary caching the file.

Ideally, there would be some way for me to have a download link and tell it to go directly to my server.  How can I accomplish this?

*I realize that this question is potentially involving a "webapp" and it is potentially involving "server administration" and since my goal is to cut my computer out of the loop I can see people saying this is off-topic and should be on another site.  My issue is this: I don't know if this is going to be a webapp solution or a server solution but I do know regardless I'm going to be using a computer to get it done and I am replacing a function that's currently done on my computer so I figured I'd ask it here.  If I was wrong and this definitely should be at webapps feel free to let me know or just migrate it.*

Answer (score 6):

You could:

- VNC into the server, load a browser, and download the file.
- SSH into the server, and do essentially the same but using the CLI (curl? wget?).  It is possible to use SSH to execute a remote command; see [ulidtko's answer for an example of this](https://superuser.com/q/241963).
- Create an application on the server that can queue up URL's of file downloads (a web service?).  It can poll the queue, downloading each file until the queue is empty.

Answer (score 3):

With CLI this is incredibly easy.

```
$ URL="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Red_Apple.jpg"
$ ssh user@remote-host 'wget $URL'

--2011-02-05 11:15:10--  http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Red_Apple.jpg
Resolving upload.wikimedia.org... 91.198.174.234
Connecting to upload.wikimedia.org|91.198.174.234|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 576216 (563K) [image/jpeg]
Saving to: `Red_Apple.jpg'

     0K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  8%  327K 2s
    50K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 17%  668K 1s
   100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 26% 1.23M 1s
   150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 35% 1.23M 1s
   200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 44%  697K 0s
   250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 53% 1.15M 0s
   300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 62%  707K 0s
   350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 71% 1.13M 0s
   400K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 79%  713K 0s
   450K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 88% 1.13M 0s
   500K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 97%  702K 0s
   550K .......... ..                                         100% 3.13M=0.7s

2011-02-05 11:15:11 (777 KB/s) - `Red_Apple.jpg' saved [576216/576216]
```

Here we use two important tools: [ssh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) and [wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget). Most output is from `wget` — but it is output of wget instance launched *on the remote machine*; the file is saved in `user`'s home directory on `remote-host`.

Comment: +1, probably the fastest way to do it and easily scriptable.

Answer (score 1):

now, this would depend if you're using shared hosting, or something with a lot more freedom. 
If its the former, it'd like have to be an ugly cludge.

If you had a VPS or some other hosting with effectively a system to yourself, you could set up what you need - say a torrent client, something like [torrentflux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TorrentFlux) if you wanted full access and/or either the aformentioned ssh/cli client method (though, if bored enough, a combination of dropbox to upload the links to the server, combined with a clever cron script would be a wonderfully abusive way of telling a system what files to open/download with what).

You might even be able to periodically compress your download into chunks for upload to save even more bandwith.

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder called "downloads" in destination server. Save this code into a `.php` file and run in destination server:

```
<html>
<form method="post">
<input name="url" size="50" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" />
</form>
<?php

// maximum execution time in seconds
set_time_limit (24 * 60 * 60);

if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) die();


// folder to save downloaded files to. must end with slash
$destination_folder = 'downloads/';

$url = $_POST['url'];
$newfname = $destination_folder . basename($url);

$file = fopen ($url, "rb");
if ($file) {
  $newf = fopen ($newfname, "wb");

  if ($newf)
  while(!feof($file)) {
    fwrite($newf, fread($file, 1024 * 8 ), 1024 * 8 );
  }
}

if ($file) {
  fclose($file);
}

if ($newf) {
  fclose($newf);
}

?>
</html>
```